# Check if nav has already class if not add one

Tags: jquery

I reached confusing point in my code. 
Here's the thing.

```
$(".main-menu").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $('nav').toggleClass("light-mode");

});
```

Basically I want to add to the click function ability:
1. Check if nav has already class "light-mode" if not, add one.
2. After user clicks second time the trigger which is ".main-menu" I want to delete added class "light-mode" so I want to more advance toggleClass.

edit:
Thanks guys for Your effort. Still I dont have a complete solution of the thing I am trying to do. My English is not so well to describe myself clear enough. 
I have a "hamburger" menu which is a one click function - trigger to show overlayed menu, and hide it. But while I click on it I also have to add a class "light-mode" to my nav, and after second click the toggler I must remove this class no matter what. And the hard thing is that I dont know how to do it using this one .click function.

toggleClass works good, but if my nav on specific page section has already this class "light-mode", the toggleClass turns it back. So when the overlay menu shows up my nav don't have the class added. That's why I cant use just the toggler. 
Your examples are half good, but on second click they are not removing the class.

Comment: Is it `.nav` or `#nav`?

Comment: I don't understand why `toggleClass` don't make the trick for you.

Comment: toggleClass does the trick for me, but, I have also second script that adds this "light-mode" on its own when user reaches specific sections of page. So... when user wants to trigger the menu when there is already a class, toggleClass simply delete its.

Comment: Is that what you want: https://jsfiddle.net/paolobasso99/b3q80gea/ ??

Comment: For your edit: just use two different class with the same CSS? This could fix your problem

Comment: @paolo.basso99, stupid to say, but You were right. I actually duplicated my .light-mode class, and renamed it. And actually, when I click the .main-menu trigger I just toggleClass into the duplicated one. Thank You ! Simpliest solutions are the best !

Comment: You are welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need [`.hasClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/), [`.addClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/) and [`.removeClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/).

Then:

```
$(".main-menu").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if ($('nav').hasClass("light-mode")) {
    $('nav').removeClass("light-mode");
  } else {
    $('nav').addClass("light-mode");
  }
});
```

Working [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/paolobasso99/b3q80gea/).

```js
$(".btn").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if ($('.example').hasClass("red")) {
    $('.example').removeClass("red");
  } else {
    $('.example').addClass("red");
  }
});
```

```css
.example {
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background-color:blue;
}

.red {
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn">
Button
</button>

<div class="example"></div>
```

You could also build a small plugin ([tutorial](https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/)) to do this easily if you want to use it more times:

```
(function( $ ){
   $.fn.classToggler = function(classToCheck, classToAddOrRemove) {
    if ($(this).hasClass(classToCheck)) {
      $(this).removeClass(classToAddOrRemove);
  } else {
      $(this).addClass(classToAddOrRemove);
  }
   }; 
})( jQuery );
```

And:

```
$(".btn").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.example').classToggler("red", "red");
});
```

Updated [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/paolobasso99/b3q80gea/2/).

```js
(function( $ ){
   $.fn.classToggler = function(classToCheck, classToAddOrRemove) {
      if ($(this).hasClass(classToAddOrRemove)) {
    $(this).removeClass(classToAddOrRemove);
  } else {
    $(this).addClass(classToAddOrRemove);
  }
   }; 
})( jQuery );

$(".btn").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.example').classToggler("red", "red");
});
```

```css
.example {
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background-color:blue;
}

.red {
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn">
Button
</button>

<div class="example"></div>
```

P.S. Since you are trying to build a "togler" you have to use `.hasClass()` because you need both `.addClass()` and `.removeClass()` inside the same .click() function and they would delete each other without an `if` statement.

Comment: Guys, I need to be more clear I guess. (my english is bad). I have the navbar trigger (first click shows the menu-overlay and adds the class, second clicks hides overlay with menu links and removes previously added class). The whole thing is about, how to do this two things (add and remove class) on the same trigger? After second click on the trigger, class should be deleted.

Comment: look my qanswer it works for what you need (it also remove the class if already exist)

Comment: Doesn't this answer solve the problem? Check if the light-mode class exist, then add/remove it. Or do you want to remove the class on second click no matter what?

Comment: @Huangism, yep. Basically I want to after second click to remove this class no matter what.

Comment: If there is no class how would you delete it?

Comment: @paolo.basso99, hard to explain, but I am having an issue on my current project with the code. I would have to give u a link to this project, but dont know how, I dont want to send it in public place, and I dont see here PM messages.

Comment: Doesn't matter, just do removeClass on second click, if no class exist then nothing happens

Comment: Yes but "removeClass()" has inside itself the function "hasClass()" so it would change nothing

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you're after for adding a class if it doesn't exist.

**UPDATE:  no need to call `hasClass`.**

```
       $('nav').addClass("light-mode");
```

2nd, you can call `removeClass` no matter what if you want to remove it...even if it doesn't exist, it is ok.

```
$('nav').removeClass("light-mode");
```

Comment: `addClass(...)` checks if the class is already there before adding it, as far as I can tell from the jQuery source

Comment: You're right.  Just like removeClass.  Good call.  Updated

Comment: Yes you need it or how would you call both .addClass() and .removeClass() in the same .click() function?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make your own toggle class then you can easily use ternary operator for this..

```
$("nav").hasClass("light-mode") ? $("nav").removeClass("light-mode"):$("nav").addClass("light-mode");
```

In you click event function.

**Edit**

As you need to add class on first click on second class you need to remove Class. SO you need to use counter variable;

```
var clickcount = 0;
$(".main-menu").click(function(e) {
  if(clickcount === 0) {
    $("nav").addClass("light-mode");
     clickcount++;
  }
  else {
    $("nav").removeClass("light-mode");
    clickcount = 0;
  }
});
```

Comment: Hm... Your example checks if there is already a class added, if there is it removes it. But I dont want to do that. All I need is to add this class no matter what, but on exit I am trying to remove the class. (on exit means, on second click on the toggler which is ".main-menu".

Comment: See Updated answer @Dawid, But I don't know how you want to add same class if it have already that class.
Means does it make sense to add Class active to element which already have active. It will not make sense.